# Django migrate/makemigrations does not work when pgAdmin4 client is running

Tags: django, postgresql, pgadmin

When the pgAdmin client is up and I give `python manage.py makemigrations`, it does nothing. It looks like it is waiting for something indefinitely. When I shutdown the client, it works fine. Is this expected?

Edit: Sorry, I meant the pgAdmin client instead of the postgres server.

Comment: These are usually unrelated processes, makemigrations only looks at the models in your project. 
Are you able to run other django processes while postgres is running? maybe the DATABASES config is not correct?

Comment: @user1464664 Sorry, I meant the pgAdmin client was running. The `check` command worked in django.

Comment: Could it be that your postgres is only allowing a single connection?

Comment: @user1464664 Could be that. I was using the same username in the pgAdmin client and in my django settings. Changed that and it was working. Changed it back to the same username and it's still working. I think I'll never know what went wrong.